# How to continue Lego microgame tutorial?

Tags: unity

I was passing Lego microgame tutorial. I closed it and quit Unity. Now, how can I continue it from the same place? If I opening it's project, I am getting just silent `Unity` project, without any guidance.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think Unity tutorials use a save/continue system. Typically when going through them I believe you are supposed to complete one or more chapters in a single sitting. The tutorial menu should allow you to pick which chapter you want to work on next, but unfortunately you will have to start from the beginning of that chapter.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, **Unity tutorials doesn’t use a save/load system, or a restart system**. As Benjamin Danger Johnson said in the comments, these projects are very short and are supposed to be completed in one sitting. You will just have to start from the beginning of the chapter you were the closest in progress to.
(I found some similar advice [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-reset-a-microgame-tutorial.1009066/).)